# Mouseover on SVG circles

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, d3.js

I'm very new to SVG, so please forgive me if this is a basic question.

I would like to draw circles on the screen and respond whenever the user mouses over each circle.

From what I can tell, when listening to mouse events on an svg, we are actually listening to mouse events on the whole canvas and not on the shapes.

If I want to handle events on the shapes, I have to use a library like D3.

Is it possible to listen to mouseOver event that are triggered when the mouse pointer passes over a specific circle?

Comment: could you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Your third sentence is incorrect. As is the fourth, no library is required, after all how do you think d3 itself does it? As to the fifth the answer is yes but you probably meant to ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No library is needed for this. Given the following SVG:

```
<svg width="500" height="500">

  <circle id="circle1" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="red"/>
  <circle id="circle2" cx="150" cy="50" r="20" fill="green"/>

</svg>
```

You could use CSS or Javascript to have these circles change in some way related to the mouse.

For a simple hover in css you can do something like:

```
#circle1:hover {
  fill: blue;
}
```

Or any JavaScript mouse event like so:

```
document.getElementById('circle2').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.currentTarget.setAttribute('fill', '#ff00cc');
});
```

Here is a demo for you to check out: 
http://codepen.io/ZevanRosser/pen/bdYyLp

Answer (score 8):

If you want this to only be svg and be able to open this in a browser and see the effect (although Zevan's answer can be embedded in svg), use something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="500" height="500">
  <circle id="circle1" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="red" onmouseover="evt.target.setAttribute('fill', 'blue');" onmouseout="evt.target.setAttribute('fill','red');"/>
  <circle id="circle2" cx="150" cy="50" r="20" fill="green" onmouseover="evt.target.setAttribute('fill', 'blue');" onmouseout="evt.target.setAttribute('fill','green');"/>
</svg>
```

the CSS option shared is cleaner, but this pattern may offer more flexibility for future mouse handling, especially if needing a function to figure out how long you want to let a user "pause" over the circle before actually modifying the property.

Answer (score -2):

Try this...

```
<circle onmousemove={() => console.log('foo') }/>
```

Comment: This is not valid SVG, since the quotes are missing. It looks like you are using some kind of framework?