# Getting the path from SVG image with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm trying to find out how I can tell what path the mouse is over in an SVG image using Javascript so I can perform an action on it.

I have a map of the UK and the SVG path looks like this:
path class="Scotland" fill="#CCCCCC" d="M262.384,105.372c-0.304.... etc, etc...

I've given each an ID as you can see in that snippet there, Scotland. All I want is to find out which path (or part of the UK) the mouse is over. I'm sure this can be achieved with Javascript but nothing I've tried is working, It must be something simple I'm missing although I've been searching for hours and not had any luck yet. I have done something similar in the past with html tables but I just can't seem to do this with these SVG paths!

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.
Dave

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint

Comment: please share `everything i tried is not working`

Answer (score 1):

A more appropriate search term for your question would be "svg hover js". With this I found [Mouseover on SVG circles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057699/mouseover-on-svg-circles)

The main difference for your case would be that you would attach the listeners to each of the paths by iterating through them automatically:

```
var shapes = document.getElementsByTagName('circle')
for (var i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) { 
  var shape = shapes[i]
  shape.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
    console.log('hover', e.currentTarget.attributes.id)
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I will give it try ;-)