# Mouse over SVG (Inkscape)

Tags: css, svg

i am new to svg and tried to replicate a simple mouseovereffect with inkscape, but my svg isnt doing a thing.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="74mm" height="105mm" viewBox="0 0 74 105">
<ellipse cx="37.042" 
cy="244.461" rx="30.994" ry="24.568"
onmouseover=fill:"red";
onmouseout=fill"none";
opacity=".75" fill="#1a1a1a" 
stroke="#000" stroke-width=".076" 
stroke-linejoin="round"
paint-order="stroke markers fill"
transform="translate(0 -192)"/>
```

Can anybody tell me what i must put into the 2 fields of the inkscapeprogramm to make it work? I searched several hours but didnt find a matching solution.
I tried it with onmousein and fill:"red" and fill:"none" onmouseout but thats also not working.

many thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mouseover on SVG circles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057699/mouseover-on-svg-circles)

Comment: The double-quotes are inconsistent in the shared code sample:

`onmouseover=fill:"red";`

should be: 

`onmouseover="fill:'red';"`

Comment: Thanks. i will try to check out what went wrong in my inkscapefile.

Answer (score 3):

onmouseover you want to change the style of the ellipse. Also as onmouseout you `fill:none`you need to add `pointer-events:all` for the ellipse to be able to interact with the mouse.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="74mm" height="105mm" viewBox="0 0 74 105">
<ellipse cx="37.042" 
cy="244.461" rx="30.994" ry="24.568"
onmouseover="this.style.fill='red'";
onmouseout="this.style.fill='none'";
opacity=".75" fill="#1a1a1a" 
stroke="#000" stroke-width=".076" 
stroke-linejoin="round"
paint-order="stroke markers fill"
pointer-events="all"
transform="translate(0 -192)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. With your code it works but mine it does nothing. Anyhow it proves to me that those onmouseover effekt is possible to achieve and i will try to figure out what went wrong in my inkscape file. thank you