# Button shaped with a function

Tags: python, button, graph

I am making a Python script which gets csv from my banking app then it plots all the data in order for me to track my budget.

[image: thin circle with a larger orange segment and a smaller blue segment]
You can see the result (there are only 2 categories there, in blue total budget and in orange what I spent

But here is my problem, I would like to be able to click on the orange and the blue parts to display more details. So I'd like to make a button shaped like the orange part.

Here is how I get my plots:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
r=1
t= np.arange(-np.pi,np.pi, 0.001)
x=r*np.sin(t)
y=r*np.cos(t)

#the coefficient is determined before but I'll just set it to 0.8 for this example
coefficient = 0.8
t1 = np.arange(-np.pi,np.pi*coefficient,0.001)
x1 = r*np.sin(t1)
y1 = r*np.cos(t1)

plt.plot(x,y,linewidth = 15 ,)
plt.plot(x1,y1,linewidth = 15)
plt.axis("equal")
plt.axis("off")
```

I could maybe create figures with my plots but I cannot find how to shape a button like a figure.
Thank you.

Comment: What platform are you planning to deploy your application? Windows? Linux? Website? There are many GUI-libraries that you could use to create clickable graphics. You can also generate a web page with an interactive SVG image: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057699/mouseover-on-svg-circles

Comment: @elechris Window for now, in html it's fairly easy to do but i'll look into that thank you !